# Drawing a hexagon

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, hexagonal-tiles

Using Firemonkey XE2 , I was able to use the `TCube` component to create a cubed map, But I am now wanting a hexagon map. There was no option for a 3d hexagon shape i could find. I figured you could create a `THex` similar to the `TCube` but I have not been able to do this or even get close. Can anyone supply a sample of doing this?

The shape I'm looking for is a [hexagon prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_prism).

[image]

Comment: A hexagon isn't a 3D Shape, [a 3D "spherical" shape using hexagonal tiles isn't really possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847654/hexagon-grid-on-sphere-without-pentagon). Do you mean to create a [Dodecahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedron)?

Comment: um, no more of a hexagon prism http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_prism

Comment: Better answer anyone! dont think any of these are worth the 500 rep

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am doing the same thing that you are doing and developing a strategic game with a hexagon map in Delphi.

You have the object that you need in Delphi itself and that is [TCylinder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Objects3D.TCylinder). 
You should **set SubdivisionAxes from 12 to 6** (12 is default for this object) and that is all you need to have the object that you want.

for implementing your map I suggest you to check this link as well.
http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

good luck.

Comment: Perfect!  Also anyway to contact you outside here. Would love to see what your working on.

Comment: @GlenMorse you can find my email in my profile. thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: Thanks got it.. going to send you something here soon.. cheers

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to derive from `TCustomMesh` and override `Render` to pass in you calculated vertices.

Start with a center and a radius and the points are as follows. Assuming the shape is constructed parallel to a plane and subsequently transformed. The following creates a vertical Hexagonal Prism (I have no IDE atm and no way of testing this!).

```
ClearPoints();
prismEnd := -1;
while prismEnd < 2 do
begin
    Z := Center.Z + (prismEnd * length)
    angle = 0;
    AddPoint(0, 0, Z);
    while angle < 360 do
    begin
        X := Center.X + (radius * Cos(DegToRad(angle)));
        Y := Center.Y + (radius * Sin(DegToRad(angle)));
        AddPoint(X, Y, Z);
        Inc(angle, 60);
    end;
    Inc(prismEnd, 2);
end;
```

For the 6 values this creates the TexCoords *should be*

```
Tex X   Tex Y 
1       0.5
0.75    1
0.25    1
0       0.5
0.25    0
0.75    0
```

You'll need 24 Triangles to render this, which depending on your draw method could require up to 72 indices.

but that will depend on how you map your textures.

I found [this link](http://delphi-science.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DelphiScience/3dUtils/FMX.MeshObjects.pas) which has examples of inheriting and using TCustomMesh

This should *in theory* provide a shape such as

[image]

Comment: Delphi has no step possibility in for loops. There is a possibility to use some of the the constructs shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16371783/576719) though.

Comment: @LURD it's been too long since I worked with Delphi I think! I'll fix it now

Comment: I understand how or the calculations on how to get the data as you have shown, but how do i incorporate this into  X component to draw it.

Comment: @GlenMorse You don't draw it, you provide vertices, indices and tex coords and pass them all to DrawTriangles in the override of the `Render` method

Comment: @JamesBarrass going to give this a try and see if i can get it working using the custom mesh..dont go far :D

Comment: @JamesBarrass ok so far i copied all of the TAnnulus stuff, with an error in the `uses FMX.Materials`  Not sure if it goes by another name or if i can download it somewhere.. Anyhow now from here i can make the `THex = class(TAnnulus)`  Correct?

Comment: You can, but you're likely replacing most of it's functionality. The TexCoords are part of the VertexBuffer in the DrawTriangles call. You can see them being assigned in the BuildAnnulus Function (Which for you becomes a BuildHex function)

Comment: @JamesBarrass thanks for the help , but i think i will need an answer with full example.  As i seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TMesh](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Objects3D.TMesh) to create whatever shape you need.

> Use the Data property to specify the points, normals and textures for
>   each point, and the order in which the resulting triangles are drawn.

All you need is precalculated points and normals for desired hexagon shape (I guess this can be found with google, or created in specialized shape editor)

Comment: i could not find them on google and still a little new to this 3d. unsure how to calculate this